# for-loop through a dict within a dict

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, average

I am having trouble with the below code:

```
{'id': 2, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '150', 'year': '2022', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id': 3, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '1220', 'year': '160', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id': 4, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '150', 'year': '2080', 'currency': 'eur'}]

total = 0
count = 0

product_search = input('product: ')
for d in l:
    name = d['name']
    for _, item in d.items():
        if item == product_search:
            total += int(d['price'])
            count += 1
            print(d['name'],d['price'])

print('average price of a {} is: {}'.format(name, total / count))
```

I am looking for the most efficient way to search the below without printing on each iteration of the for loop.

I have devised the below code but the output iterates over each dict and prints the output 'not in list'.

```
product_search = input('product: ')
for d in l:
    name = d['name']
    for _, item in d.items():
        if item == product_search:
            total += int(d['price'])
            count += 1
            print(d['name'],d['price'])
        if product_search != item:
            print('not in list')

print('average price of a {} is: {}'.format(name, total / count))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
from statistics import fmean
product_search = input('product: ')
avg = mean(
    int(d['price'])
    for d in l
    if d['name'] == product_search
)
print(f'average price of a {product_search} is: {avg}')
```

Output

```
product:  apple

average price of a apple is: 506.6666666666667
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import statistics as stats

l = [{'id': 2, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '150', 'year': '2022', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id': 3, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '1220', 'year': '160', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id': 4, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '150', 'year': '2080', 'currency': 'eur'}]

product = 'apple'

prices = [float(d['price']) for d in l if d['name'] == product]

mean_price = stats.mean(prices) if len(prices) > 0 else None

if mean_price is not None:
    print(f'The mean price of {product} is {mean_price:.2f}')
else:
    print('Not in list')
```

Edit:

I think your code snippet is missing an "l = [" at the very beginning, in which case you are actually looking at a list of dictionaries not a dictionary of dictionaries. Not a big deal, just want to make sure the terminology is straight.

As for your code itself, the first for loop is fine. However, in the second for loop, you are actually looking through each dictionary item when you only need to look at the 'name' key in the dictionary.

For example, when you look at the first dictionary, you are comparing 2 == product and then 'apple' == product then '150' == product, etc... You really only need "if name == product" That's why you are printing a lot of "not in list" because you are comparing apples to oranges so to speak.

Finally, it's a small thing, but your two if statements can be turned into an if-else combination instead since if it fails the first test, it automatically passes the second. If you use two if-statements that are covering the same essential test, the code will check twice. It's an extremely minor efficiency issue for this problem, but it's a good habit to make sure you're not over-testing with if statements.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed review, how would i go about incorporating the below into your code? @michaelcao

if int(d['year']) >= mid_year-10 and int(d['year']) <= mid_year+10:

Comment: Do you mean you only want prices that are within 10 years of mid_year? You can add that additional condition as:

prices = [float(d['price']) for d in l if d['name'] == product and abs(int(d['year']) - mid_year) <= 10 ]

For reference, you can also search "python list comprehension" if you want to learn more about what that particular line of code is doing.

Comment: thank you Micahel, that is correct - so say if mid_year was = 2010. I want to only average the price from 2000 -> 2020.

Comment: I think i have sussed it with this code here: prices = [float(d['price']) for d in l if d['name'] == product and int(d['year']) >= mid_year-10 and int(d['year']) <= mid_year+10 ]

Comment: Yes, you can either express that as two conditions or just take the absolute difference check that it's under 10.